# Rethrow exceptions while streaming

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-8, java-stream

I'm having trouble rethrowing exceptions thrown by stream while "accessing" it.

For example, if I have a stream which throws `ExceptionA`:

```
Stream<String> stream = Stream.of("dummy").map(d -> {throw new ExceptionA();});

try {
   stream.collect(Collectors.toList());
} catch (ExceptionA e) {}
```

What I want to achieve is create new `stream2` out of `stream` **without consuming** `stream` which will throw `ExceptionB` when it's collected

```
try {
   stream2.collect(Collectors.toList());
} catch (ExceptionB e) {}
```

Obviously

```
Iterator<String> newIt = createRethrowingIterator(stream.iterator());
Stream<String> stream2 = StreamSupport.stream(Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize(newIt, Spliterator.NONNULL), false)
```

where `createRethrowingIterator` wraps original iterator and returns new one which actually rethrows `ExceptionA` to `ExceptionB`

is not what I want as `stream.iterator()` is terminal operator, i.e. it will consume stream, which might lead to memory problems if stream is really large

Comment: What makes you think it'll actually consume the stream?

Comment: Because of third paragraph of "Stream operations and pipelines" https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html and https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/BaseStream.html#iterator--

Comment: That does _not_ mean it'll actually iterate over the stream or generate it in memory.  It means the stream is considered "consumed," which means it can't be reused, but that doesn't mean it's actually materialized in memory or will cause memory problems generally.

Comment: Hmm, that seems pretty logical, gonna check it soon. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This task is better solved using `Spliterator` rather than `Iterator`. It simplifies the logic, as you only have to implement a single method, `tryAdvance`, by delegating the the source’s `tryAdvance` method.

It also opens the opportunity for performance improvements by delegating the methods `characteristics()` and `estimateSize()` to the source, as the exception translation feature does not change them. You can also get decent parallel support, by implementing `trySplit` via delegating to the source. You only have to wrap the result exactly like the first `Spliterator`:

```
public class Rethrowing<T,E extends Throwable> implements Spliterator<T> {
    public static <E extends Throwable, T> Stream<T> translateExceptions(
        Stream<T> source, Class<E> catchType,
        Function<? super E, ? extends RuntimeException> translator) {

        return StreamSupport.stream(new Rethrowing<>(
            source.spliterator(), catchType, translator), source.isParallel());
    }
    private final Spliterator<T> source;
    private final Class<E> catchType;
    private final Function<? super E, ? extends RuntimeException> translator;

    public Rethrowing(Spliterator<T> sp, Class<E> catchType,
            Function<? super E, ? extends RuntimeException> translator) {
        this.source = sp;
        this.catchType = catchType;
        this.translator = translator;
    }
    @Override public boolean tryAdvance(Consumer<? super T> action) {
        try { return source.tryAdvance(action); }
        catch(Throwable t) {
            if(catchType.isInstance(t))
                throw translator.apply(catchType.cast(t));
            else throw t;
        }
    }
    @Override public int characteristics() {
        return source.characteristics();
    }
    @Override public long estimateSize() {
        return source.estimateSize();
    }
    @Override public Spliterator<T> trySplit() {
        Spliterator<T> split = source.trySplit();
        return split==null? null: new Rethrowing<>(split, catchType, translator);
    }
}
```

you can use this utility class like

```
class ExceptionA extends IllegalStateException {
    public ExceptionA(String s) {
        super(s);
    }
}
class ExceptionB extends IllegalStateException {
    public ExceptionB(Throwable cause) {
        super(cause);
    }
}
Rethrowing.translateExceptions(
    Stream.of("foo", "bar", "baz", "", "extra")
        .peek(s -> System.err.println("consuming \""+s+'"'))
        .map(s -> { if(s.isEmpty()) throw new ExceptionA("empty"); return s; }),
    ExceptionA.class, ExceptionB::new)
        .forEach(s -> System.err.println("terminal operation on "+s));
```

to get

```
consuming "foo"
terminal operation on foo
consuming "bar"
terminal operation on bar
consuming "baz"
terminal operation on baz
consuming ""
Exception in thread "main" ExceptionB: ExceptionA: empty
…
Caused by: ExceptionA: empty
…
```

Here, `ExceptionB::new` is the translation function, which is equivalent to `exA->new ExceptionB(exA)`.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you wrap that call which throws your `ExceptionA` into a mapping function which if thrown transforms it into `ExceptionB` immediately, like:

```
try {
  List<T> l = stream.map(o -> wrapped(() -> o.whateverThrowsExceptionA())).collect(toList());
  // or do your stream2 operations first, before collecting the list
} catch (ExceptionB b) {
  // handle your exception
}
```

where `wrapped` in that case would be similar to:

```
<T> T wrapped(Callable<T> o) throws ExceptionB {
  try {
    return callable.call();
  } catch (Exception e) {
    throw new ExceptionB(e);
  }
}
```

You may even want to adjust the wrapper to take in a custom `ExceptionA`-catching function.

Comment: Source stream comes from the API which I can not modify and exception can be thrown before execution reaches `wrapped(o)`. So I'm afraid this won't work

Comment: adjusted the answer a bit. Even if the exception is now thrown by an external API, you can catch it that way, without separate try/catch statements surrounding your stream. You can even switch to a `RuntimeException` that way. Whether that makes sense, depends on the use case.

Comment: Problem is that there is no such thing as `o.whateverThrowsExceptionA()`, exception from the stream can be thrown during materialization of `o`. So I can not wrap it with try/catch the way you proposed here. I think I failed to understand what terminal operation really means, so if what @Louis Wasserman suggested is correct, solution would be the way I described in my OP

Comment: If you wrap whatever is throwing that `ExceptionA` into the `Callable` and use `wrapped(() -> ...)` there is no way that you miss the exception... I don't know in which case the materialization of the stream should lead to `ExceptionA`, except in the mapping case. But then you need to surround the mapping and not the collecting part. Or is `ExceptionA` rather a `RuntimeException` which is thrown from the `Collector` itself?

Comment: I don't have direct access to the part of code which throws `ExceptionA`, it is behind the API which provides stream (however I achieved desired behaviour, see below), and yes, exception is thrown from the `Collector` itself, as  this is what causes stream to be materialized. See my post to demonstrate what I mean: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42998615/1451174

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I failed to understand that terminal operation does not mean that stream is fully consumed. Thank you Louis Wasserman for clarifying this.

To demonstrate it I wrote some unit tests:

```
import org.junit.Test;

import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Spliterator;
import java.util.Spliterators;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;
import java.util.stream.StreamSupport;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;
import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThatThrownBy;

/**
 * @author Beka Tsotsoria
 */
public class StreamExceptionRethrowingTest {

    @Test
    public void throwingIteratorMustBeConsumedWhenStreamIsCollected() throws Exception {
        ThrowingIterator itToBeConsumed = new ThrowingIterator();

        assertThatThrownBy(() -> streamFromIterator(itToBeConsumed)
            .collect(Collectors.toList()))
            .isInstanceOf(ExceptionA.class);

        assertThat(itToBeConsumed.consumed()).isTrue();
    }

    @Test
    public void throwingIteratorMustNotBeConsumedUntilNewStreamIsCollected() throws Exception {
        ThrowingIterator itNotToBeConsumed = new ThrowingIterator();
        RethrowingIterator rethrowingIterator = new RethrowingIterator(streamFromIterator(itNotToBeConsumed).iterator());

        assertThat(itNotToBeConsumed.consumed()).isFalse();

        Stream<String> stream2 = streamFromIterator(rethrowingIterator);

        assertThat(itNotToBeConsumed.consumed()).isFalse();

        assertThatThrownBy(() -> stream2
            .collect(Collectors.toList()))
            .hasCauseInstanceOf(ExceptionA.class)
            .isInstanceOf(ExceptionB.class);

        assertThat(itNotToBeConsumed.consumed()).isTrue();
    }

    @Test
    public void streamIteratorMustNotBeConsumedUntilNewStreamIsCollected() throws Exception {
        Stream<String> stream = Stream.of("dummy")
            .map(d -> {
                throw new ExceptionA();
            });

        Stream<String> stream2 = streamFromIterator(new RethrowingIterator(stream.iterator()));
        // No exceptions so far, i.e. stream.iterator() was not consumed

        assertThatThrownBy(() -> stream2
            .collect(Collectors.toList()))
            .hasCauseInstanceOf(ExceptionA.class)
            .isInstanceOf(ExceptionB.class);
    }

    private Stream<String> streamFromIterator(Iterator<String> it) {
        return StreamSupport.stream(Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize(it, Spliterator.NONNULL), false);
    }

    static class ThrowingIterator implements Iterator<String> {

        private boolean hasNextCalled;
        private boolean nextCalled;

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            hasNextCalled = true;
            throw new ExceptionA();
        }

        @Override
        public String next() {
            nextCalled = true;
            throw new ExceptionA();
        }

        public boolean consumed() {
            return hasNextCalled || nextCalled;
        }
    }

    static class RethrowingIterator implements Iterator<String> {

        private Iterator<String> it;

        public RethrowingIterator(Iterator<String> it) {
            this.it = it;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            try {
                return it.hasNext();
            } catch (ExceptionA e) {
                throw new ExceptionB(e);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public String next() {
            try {
                return it.next();
            } catch (ExceptionA e) {
                throw new ExceptionB(e);
            }
        }
    }


    static class ExceptionA extends RuntimeException {

    }

    static class ExceptionB extends RuntimeException {

        public ExceptionB(Throwable cause) {
            super(cause);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for your comments. Cheers!

Comment: You should really learn about the `Spliterator` interface. It really simplifies implementing such operations. And you don’t end up with twenty thousand wrapped objects.

Comment: `Spliterator` looks like mysterious thing for me at the moment. I should definitely learn it!